# Releveling multiple factors with a common word

Tags: r, recode, levels, mutate

Apologies, pretty new to R and I'm struggling with releveling multiple variables that have a common element/word.

What I want to do is mutate all variables that have a common word in the same way.

All variables with "Result" in the name should be releveled as "Pass", "Fail" - in that order.
All variables with "Tutorial" in the name should be releveled as "Yes", "No", "Unscheduled" - in that order.

An example of my dataset would be like this;

```
Exam_1_Test_Result<-c("Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Fail") 
Exam_1_Test_Tutorial<-c("Yes","Yes","No","Unscheduled","No") 
Exam_1_Test_Score<-c("55","65","65","50","45")

Exam_2_Test_Result<-c("Fail","Fail","Pass","Fail","Fail") 
Exam_2_Test_Tutorial<-c("No","Yes","Unscheduled","No","Yes") 
Exam_2_Test_Score<-c("35","45","65","50","35")

df<-data.frame(Exam_1_Test_Result,Exam_1_Test_Tutorial,Exam_1_Test_Score,
Exam_2_Test_Result,Exam_2_Test_Tutorial,Exam_2_Test_Score)
```

I am passing this data to gtsummary and the data just appears alphabetically in the table output.

I have tried various combinations of mutate, but none seem to work for me.
The following code I found on stack overflow works for me for the first variable but then stops working for the second variable. i.e., it reverts back to alphabetical in the outputted table.

```
pf<- c("Pass", "Fail")
df<-df%>% mutate_at(vars(contains("Result")), ~fct_relevel(.x, pf))

tutorial<- c("Yes", "No", "Unscheduled")
df<-df%>% mutate_at(vars(contains("Tutorial")), ~fct_relevel(.x, tutorial))
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! With `df<-data.frame("Exam_1_Test_Result", ...`, do you mean `df<-data.frame(Exam_1_Test_Result, ...` (without quotes)?

Comment: Then what do you mean by "stops working"? If I run your code, I get what seems to be the desired output. Checking with e.g. `levels(df$Exam_1_Test_Tutorial)`, gives `[1] "Yes"         "No"          "Unscheduled"`

Comment: Yes, apologies. I've edited my post now to reflect this.

Comment: When I pass the data to gtsummary, the levels revert back to alphabetical in the table output.

Comment: With `gtsummary::tbl_summary(df)`, factors are ordered as expected (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtjkv.png ). What is your `packageVersion("gtsummary")`? If not latest on CRAN (1.7.1), try to update

Comment: My gtsummary is 1.7.1 but the problem still persists in my real dataset. The mock dataset works perfectly. I think I will just have to relevel them indicidually.